# Jquery select elements between two specials elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i get all `<dd>` elements exists between first and second `<dt>`

**Identities are not static, only `<dl id="allData">` is static !!**

```
<div>
   <dl id="allData">
      <dt id="f">Data :</dt>
      <dd id="sd">A</dd>
      <dd id="bf">B</dd>
      <dd id="r3">C</dd>
      <dd id="br">D</dd>
       .
       .
      <dd id="u6">L</dd>

      <dt id="f1">Data1</dt>
      <dd id="dw">A</dd>
      <dd id="jy">B</dd>
      <dd id="5d">C</dd>
      <dd id="gg">D</dd>
       .
       .
      <dd id="2s">K</dd>
   </dl>
</div>
```

And how can i get all `<dd>` elements of `<dl id='allData'>` if i have one `<dt>` element ?

Comment: Please without use id ..

Comment: What part of your data is static? Is text within <dt></dt> static? Is order static?

Comment: only `<dl id="allData">` static, and other elements can be different ..

Answer (score 1):

You can use the element indexes:

```
var i1 = $(document.getElementById(id1)).index(),
    i2 = $(document.getElementById(id2)).index(),
    $elements = $('#allData dd').filter(function(){
      var i = $(this).index(); return i1<i && i<i2
    });
```

```js
var i1 = $('#f').index(),
    i2 = $('#f1').index(),
    $elements = $('#allData dd').filter(function(){
      var i = $(this).index(); return i1<i && i<i2
    });

// print the result on the snippet
document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify($elements.map(function(){ return this.id }).get());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
   <dl id="allData">
      <dt id="f">Data :</dt>
      <dd id="sd">A</dd>
      <dd id="bf">B</dd>
      <dd id="r3">C</dd>
      <dd id="br">D</dd>
       .
       .
      <dd id="u6">L</dd>

      <dt id="f1">Data1</dt>
      <dd id="dw">A</dd>
      <dd id="jy">B</dd>
      <dd id="5d">C</dd>
      <dd id="gg">D</dd>
       .
       .
      <dd id="2s">K</dd>
   </dl>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there another way without the use of identities?

Comment: What do you have instead ?

Comment: `f` and `f1` are not static ids !!

Comment: what is the value of id1 and id2 ?

Comment: Based on your code: instead of `i1` use `$($("#allData dt")[0]).index()` and istead of `i2` use `$($("#allData dt")[1]).index()`

Comment: `i2` use `$($("#allData dt")[0]).index()` or `$($("#allData dt")[1]).index()` ?

Comment: `$($("#allData dt")[1]).index()`. I forgot to fix 0 to 1 when i copied the text :)

Comment: please one more question.. In some cases, it may be one `<dt>` element, how can i get all `<dd>` ?

Comment: @Nomeaning25 No: your solution is slower and less safe (it doesn't work for many valid ids)

Comment: @DenysSéguret But he has no id's. All id's are probably auto generated each time the page builds. What about `$(document.getElementsByTagName("dt")[0])`. Would that be any faster

Answer (score 1):

**You can try this**

```
var $selected_siblings= $('#f').nextUntil('#f1');
```

*//as per your new requirement try this*

**`$("#allData").children("dt").slice(0,1)`**.watever_method_you want to try

Comment: Is there another way without the use of identities ?

Comment: for selection you need  ID or class atleast :)

Comment: `allData` id for `<dl>` is not enough ?

Comment: than basis of what you want to select ??? allData is parent id ..it  can be used to select all dd

Comment: please one more question.. In some cases, it may be one `<dt>` element, how can i get all `<dd>` ?

Comment: @TalalFarhat  you can use `.length` method to count the number of `dt` and than `$('#allData').find('dd')` will select all `dd` ....try this

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for @denys-séguret and @nomeaning25

**Result :**

```
var i1 = $($("#allData dt")[0]).index(),
    i2 = $($("#allData dt")[1]).index(),
    $elements = $('#allData dd').filter(function () {
        var i = $(this).index();
        return i1 < i && i < i2
    });

console.log(JSON.stringify($elements.map(function () {
    return this.id
}).get()));
```

and thanks for @yo-yo

**Result:**

```
console.log($("#allData").children("dt").slice(0, 1));
```

Comment: You should rather use `document.getElementById` as in my answer: it's faster and safer (it works whatever the ID).

Comment: @TalalFarhat If there is a posibility you have only one `<dt>` then i would put `if` clause in your function that would check if `$("#allData dt").size()` is greater than one. if it equals 1 then your elemenst are `$elements = $('#allData dd')`